# How do I replace Year in data frame and multiply that value with 12 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace String which is Year/years with 12 and perform multiplication operation on that value 
Below is the sample dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ten_in_Months' : ['1 year','2 years','3 years','40','50',],'paid_by' : ['hi', 
                  'foo', 'fat', 'cat','dog']})
```

what I need is 1 year is replaced with 12 , 2 years with 24 , 3 years with 36

`df['ten_in_months'].mul([12], axis=0)`

I don't know how can I use regex to find that year replace and multiply with 12 * ($)

Comment: if the field doesn't contain `years` do you want to treat it as months?

Comment: yes , other records are all months, I need to convert wherever there is year/years to months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the entries without a `"year"` string as months then you can use the following code

```
df['ten_in_Months'] = df['ten_in_Months'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('year')[0])*12 if len(x.split('year')) > 1 else x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` to get the number representing the year:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['ten_in_Months'].str.extract('(\\d+) years?')[0]) * 12
df['ten_in_Months'] = m.combine_first(df['ten_in_Months']).astype('int')
```

Comment: Old habit from my C days

Comment: `\d` matches a digit in Regex but `\ ` is also an escape character for literal strings. Hence the double `\\ ` so that `\d` is passed down to the regex engine

Comment: I see. I initially assumed it was just a typo :) Thx was unaware of this

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
pat = r'(\d+)\syear(?:s)?$'
m = df.ten_in_Months.str.match(pat)
months = df.ten_in_Months.str.extract(pat).squeeze().astype(float).mul(12)
df['ten_in_Months'] = df['ten_in_Months'].mask(m, months) 

print(df)

 ten_in_Months paid_by
0            12      hi
1            24     foo
2            36     fat
3            40     cat
4            50     dog
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `extract` all numbers and with the help of `mask` multiply only cells that `contains` `'year'`:

```
s = df['ten_in_Months']

df['ten_in_Months'] = s.str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int).\
mask(s.str.contains('year'), lambda x: x * 12)
```